# Upgrading an existing cordova cli project from 3.3.1 to 3.5

Tags: android, ios, node.js, cordova, cordova-3

I have a cordova cli project created with cordova 3.3.1. I want to upgrade to 3.5 as it includes a bunch of fixes/feature implementations that are going to be very useful to me.

Can I just go ahead and update the cordova npm package and update platforms (iOS and Android) as described here : http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/05/23/cordova-350.html ?

AFAIK, the directory structure of the app changed somewhat since 3.4, at least the location of config.xml has changed. I did not find any docs advising restructuring the project directories and/or files.

So I wonder if the newer version of cordova will be able to find the files in older locations and build the project successfully.

Any info of upgrading my project in a clean and safe way will be very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There where some changes with the structure for the "hooks" and the ".cordova" folder but everything should be backwards compatible I believe.
I did the same a week back and everything kept working including the cordova hooks.
So a

```
npm install -g cordova
cordova platform update <platform>
```

Should be sufficient!